# Variable changes value when passed to function?

Tags: c++

I feel like an idiot. When I pass a variable to the function it results in a strange output like 6.2+e003 instead of the value that the variable holds. What am I doing wrong?

The x in main and the x in the function are different?

main:

```
int x, y;

while(system.WindowOpen())
{
    x++;
    y++;
    bg.Draw2D();
    bob.Think(x, y);
    riley.Think(x, y);
    system.Render(0);
}
```

class method:

```
void Organism::Think(double x, double y)
{
    std::cout << "X: " << x << "\n";
    std::vector<double> food;
    food.push_back(x);
    food.push_back(y);
    std::cout << "VECTOR: " << food[0] << " " << food[1] << "\n";
    std::vector<double> path;
    if(refresh.IsTime()) {
        std::cout << "\nFOOD VECTOR: \n" << food[0]
                  << "\n" << food[1] << "\n";

        path = brian.GetOutput(food);


        organism.Translate2D(path[0], path[1]);

        if(organism.IsOffScreen2D(resX, resY) == 'l' )
            organism.SetPos2D(resX, organism.GetY());
        if(organism.IsOffScreen2D(resX, resY) == 'r')
            organism.SetPos2D(0, organism.GetY());
        if(organism.IsOffScreen2D(resX, resY) == 't')
            organism.SetPos2D(organism.GetX(), resY);
        if(organism.IsOffScreen2D(resX, resY) == 'b')
            organism.SetPos2D(organism.GetX(), 0);
    };

    font.DrawNumber2D(x, 50, 50);
    font.DrawNumber2D(y, 50, 100);
    organism.Draw2D();
}
```

Comment: Is this the actual code because these variables are uninitialized which explains the random value.

Comment: `6.2+e003` is `6200`. And why are you passing integers to function that expect doubles? Also remember that `x` and `y` is not initialized, so you cannot predict what values they have

Comment: X and Y where doubles initially, just trying other datatypes to see if it would fix the problem. Even the variables initialized, it still has the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Both `x` and `y` are uninitialized here:

```
int x, y;
```

so they can hold any value, and reading from them is undefined behaviour. You should initialize them:

```
int x = 0
int y = 0;
```

Comment: I did try that, still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was writing outside the bounds of a vector. I switched from using the `[]` operators to using the `.at()` and found my bug right away. Just a bit of memory corruption. I feel quite silly. Thanks all!